# MSDE 2000 to MSSQL 2008 SQLExpress replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have an old database on MSDE which I need to replicate (one-time process) to a new MSSQL 2008 SQLExpress installation.  What are my best options to replicate without involving messy sql scripting?  I know there are some "layman can use" paid software out there such as dbconvert.  I wouldn't want to use them as far as possible but will consider if there are no other alternatives.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you need replication. Sounds like you need to restore your old database to the new MSSQL 2008 Express instance.

Right-click the database, select All Tasks -> Backup Database. Add a destination file (*.bak) and perform a Complete backup.

In SQL 2008 MS, right-click Databases and select Restore Database. Input a name for a new database and select the backup. After the restore operation is done, the database will be upgraded to SQL2008 automatically.

For more info on restore on 2008 check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx), for backup and restore operations on SQL 2000 check [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966495.aspx)

Comment: +1 Agreed, backup and restore is the best option for a one time migration.  Don't forget to change the compatibility mode to 100 afterwards, assuming your application supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

- DTS Wizard/packages
- SSIS packages